# Limit objects in has_many assosiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to limit the number of possible objects in a `has_many` association. I have 2 models `Container` and `Can`.

`Container` has no limit but only `12` cans may exist in one container.

I was able to limit the cans with the `:limit => 12` but they are not per container.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: What's the context of your problem?

Comment: i have an infinite number of containers, but only 12 cans per container. this is a requirement that must be met

you could equate the problem with a parking garage.

you have individual parking decks that only have a certain number of parking spaces available.

Comment: Do you mean like disabling the insert of cans per container if there are already 12 in the database? Is it a query you're doing? Something else?

Comment: a check with before_save would be enough at the end

I'm just not sure how I'm gonna make this work.
one idea would be to check the number of current objects in the container where I store the new can and then use before_save to get an error

Comment: What about a database trigger before the insertion?

Comment: You need both a validation (or callback) on the application side and a constraint inthe database to avoid [possible race conditions](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from `before_create` `ActiveRecord` callback

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cans
end

class Can < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container

  before_create :check_overflow

  def check_overflow
    throw(:abort) if container.cans.count >= 12
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situations like yours. I did it as shown below,

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cans

  validate :no_of_cans

  def no_of_cans
    if cans.size > 12
       errors.add(:base, 'Container is limited to 12 cans!')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is still prone to possible race conditions. To safeguard against that you need to compliment this with a database constraint.